# Can't get Ionic's datetime picker to work and showup even

Tags: angularjs, datetime, ionic-framework, datetimepicker

check example on docs: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/datetime/DateTime/
and https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#datetime

I'm making mobile-app with ionic+angular+cordova in VS.
And I want to use simple datetime picker they have on their docs, with year, month & day. As those native looking scrollable selectors.

I've tried this in my page:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Date:</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime displayFormat="YYYY-MM-DD" [(ngModel)]="myDate"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

and js:

```
$scope.myDate = new Date();
$scope.myDate.toISOString();
```

But nothing else shows up except ion-item and ion-label. How do I make the 'ion-datetime'-element work?

Comment: try this `$scope.myDate = new Date().toISOString();`

Comment: @IssamELATIF well that just shorten's the code, but It doesn't show the ion-datetime-element still, that's the problem.

Comment: Why displayFormat is uppercase `YYYY-MM-DD`? It should be `yyyy-MM-dd`

Comment: @IssamELATIF because example is in that format. I tried changing it to `displayFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"` still not showing :(

Comment: Ionic 2 is built on top of Angular 2 and Angular 2 is using `this` instead of `$scope` . try `this.myDate = new Date().toISOString();`

Comment: Oh yeah, that's the problem Do'h! I'm using old version of both..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using wrong version of Angular and Ionic(1.3). I need to use atleast Ionic 2 and AngularJS 2 to make the datetimepicker work. Other choice is to add it through plugins..

Answer (score 0):

The documentation link you provide is for Ionic 2

Ionic 2 is built on top of Angular 2 and Angular 2 is using `this` instead of `$scope` . try `this.myDate = new Date().toISOString();`

If you are not using Ionic 2 but Ionic 1 change `[(ngModel)]="myDate"` to `ngModel="myDate"`. Your page should look like

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Date:</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime displayFormat="YYYY-MM-DD" ngModel="myDate"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: I don't think ionic 1.3 has ion-datetime-element? You need plugins for that. I've tried changing it to `ng-model="myDate"`

Comment: Ah I see! I used Ionic 1 once but I am not an expert of Ionic. Glad that helps you figure out the issue.

Comment: Yeah me neither, just checked the docs. Thanks for helping though :) I probably start using ionic 2 then.